# An arithmetic sequence of numbers without certain prime factors

Tags: number-theory

I just attended a lecture at my school about prime numbers and the idea of being coprime and what kind of applications that has, and this question popped up in my head and I thought about it for a while and asked a few friends and wasn't quite sure what to think. One of my friends told me about this website so I thought I would give it a shot. So here's the question:

What is the largest arithmetic sequence (most amount of terms) such that none of its terms are divisible by the first $n$ prime numbers, and which all of its terms are less than $n\#$ (where $\#$ denotes the primorial function)?

For example, for $n = 2$ the largest such sequence would be $1, 5$ and for $n = 3$ the largest such sequence would be $1, 7, 13, 19$ or $11, 17, 23, 29$.

Comment: For the $n=2$ case the example you gave can be extended indefinitely since if you keep adding $4$ you will continue to have only odd numbers in the sequence.

Comment: To satisfy the first case, sure, but the second requirement is that the each term be less than $n\#$, where $n\# = \prod_{k = 1}^n p_k$. So in the case of $n = 2$, the upper bound is $2 \times 3 = 6$

Ah, and you also misunderstood what $n=2$ meant. $n=2$ meant the first two prime numbers, i.e. $2$ and $3$.

Comment: You're right, for some reason I was thinking primes $\leq n$. Also I stopped reading before the second condition apparently... An easy result though is, letting $a_0=1$, the smallest common difference between terms is $p_{n+1}−1$ since the second term must be at least $p_{n+1}$. Given this and the second condition, an upper bound on the length of such a sequence is $\left \lfloor \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}p_n-2}{p_{n+1}-1} \right \rfloor +1$.

Comment: But if you were not to start at 1, aren't you able to find valid numbers with a gap of less than $p_{n+1} - 1$? Regardless, I don't think this will result in any kind of solution. Thanks for the contribution, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Patrick said, the only available terms that are the products of two primes $p, q$ (or $1$) where $p, q > p_n$. So for $4\#$ you would have $1, 11, 11 \times 11, 11 \times 13, 11 \times 17, 11 \times 19, 13, 13 \times 13, 17, 19, 23, 27,$ (along with the rest of primes less than $210$).

In its current state, it looks like these arithmetic progressions are going to be awfully low in number, and depend on arithmetic progressions found in prime numbers, which is pretty low as well. More about primes in arithmetic progression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeArithmeticProgression.html

Not a full answer by any means, but some guiding tips.